# Permission denied when deleting file in PHP

Tags: php

This is driving me crazy already, cant delete a directory and its content using code:

```
    public function deleteDirectory($path) { 
     $files = glob($path . '/*');
     foreach ($files as $file) {
        is_dir($file) ? self::deleteDirectory($file) : unlink($file);
     }
     rmdir($path);
     return;
    }
```

As I can see it is able to delete the folder, but when it comes to the file which i guess unlink($file) case, it doesnt allow me to delete bc of permission issue. I have no idea what can I do at the moment, any help would appreciate it alot.

Comment: add a chmod directive for the file(s) also; if on Linux. chown if on Windows

Comment: do you have write permissons on the containing directory? deleting a file requires updating the container dir, which means you need write permissons on it. e.g. `rm /foo/bar/baz` means you have to have `+w` on /foo/bar

Comment: non-static methods should be called using `$this` or late-static-binding `static::deleteDirectorey()`, or you make it `public static function deleteDirectory()`. Stoneage 5.3 will excuse, 5.6 won't :-D

Comment: @Fred-ii- `chown if on Windows` why did you say that?!

Comment: @revo question is... why did "you" say that *"You should work with chown"* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You limited chown to Windows and that's the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the user who is executing the PHP Code you gave.
Are you running it as sudo or someone **who has access to that directory & files** ?

Possibly this PHP Code is **being run by www-data, nginx, or some user like this**, which **don't have permission** to that directory. Check the permission, and try again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81292/discussion-on-answer-by-skbly7-permission-denied-when-deleting-file-in-php).